# Azure, deploy webapp, resource_group_name

Tags: azure

Following this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-html

When running `az webapp up --location westeurope --name myapp`

I get:

```
Parameter 'resource_group_name' must conform to the following pattern: '^[-\\w\\._\\(\\)]+$'.
```

> According to docs:
>
> The az webapp up command does the following actions:
>
> **Create a default resource group**.

?

Comment: ok, just delete that comment. I've just tried the same code and it worked (after I changed `myapp` to something unique). so try updating `az`? or try using `https://shell.azure.com/`?

Comment: @Joe Has your issue been resolved?

Comment: @TonyJu. Yes. It was a temporary error. Found a workaround posted by an author.